# css selectors, set property for all except two tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a modal and i try to implement nested comments
now i want to send the parent comment id to child comment in modal

button that show modal:

```html
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-light" data-target="#commentModal" data-toggle="modal" data-parent="3">پاسخ</button>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="commentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="commentModal" aria-hidden="true" dir="rtl">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                <h4 id="modal-label-3" class="modal-title">ارسال نظر</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="respond-form" id="respond" style="padding-top: 0">
                    <form action="/comment" class="form-gray-fields">

                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="0">

                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group text-center">
                                    <button class="btn btn-block" type="submit">ثبت دیدگاه</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to send value of data-parent in button, to "vlaue" attribute of input in modal

i see this for bootstrap modals:

```js
$('#commentModal').on('show.bs.modal' , function (event) {
    let button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    let parentId = button.data('parent');
    let modal = $(this);
    modal.find("[name='parent_id']").val(parentId);
});
```

but i do not use bootstrap and following code not working for me!

Comment: What approach are you using to show the modal? Does the modal already exist on the page? Are you fetching the modal content via ajax?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$(".btn").on("click", function(){
    $(".modal-body").find("[name=parent_id]").val($(this).data("parent"));
    // Code to show modal
});
```

Comment: Looks like an ending parenthesis ran away. `.val($(this).data("parent");` should be `.val($(this).data("parent"));`